# Prove that if A and B are independent, then they are independent conditional to any event C.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

So far I have:

P(AnB)=P(a)*P(B) because the two events are independent (given in statement). I know we need to show:

P(AnB|C)=P(A|C)*P(B|C).. Is this right?

Comment: You might try $C = (A \cap B)^c$.

Comment: So is the answer that if the two events are independent then they are not independent conditional to C

Comment: No, they may or may not be conditionally independent.

Comment: Im confused by what you mean by "may or may not be". I am trying to prove:

Comment: Is there any way to prove that this statement is mathematically true or do I assume it is just false?

Comment: There are some $C$ such that $P(A \cap B \mid C) = P(A \mid C) P(B \mid C)$.  There may be some $C$ such that $P(A \cap B \mid C) \ne P(A \mid C) P(B \mid C)$.

Comment: And thus the statement is false.

Comment: Can you give an example of which A and B are independent but not independent conditional to C?

Comment: @Taffies1 Such an example was already given in the question that we marked this a duplicate of.